# asp.net mvc 4 injecting dependencies into different controller types

Tags: unity-container, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using both types of controllers available in MVC 4: System.Web.Mvc.Controller and System.Web.Http.ApiController. I need to be able to inject dependencies into the controllers using Unity.

For the ApiControllers I am using Unity.WebApi:
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(_container);

For the Controllers I tried using Unity.Mvc3 which I added using Nuget:
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Unity.Mvc3.UnityDependencyResolver(_container));

However, I get a runtime error:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Does anyone know of a solution that works for this situation?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a binding redirect in your web.config:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>      
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```